# use form select tag instead of iframe

Tags: html, css, list, iframe, scroll

I have a sidebar that's about 200px wide and 300px tall. My list of links has grown to fill the entire 300px sidebar. I am not sure which route I should go from here:

Option 1) iFrame the list and have the user scroll through it

Option 2) use select form and expand it to fill the 300px and the user can scroll within that.

Which is the correct html5 way of handling this? Going beyond 300px tall is not possible.

Comment: do not use iframe for this, use overflow if needed or if  some of your links can be bnested , use a dropdown menu. be aware that dropdown menu growing big are a problem too and are often inefficient to let visitors know what can be found on your site. the select form was the 90's way of building dropdown menus :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to use a Iframe, if you have a fixed hieght of div and overflow:auto, you can easly scroll down your items.